# Can someone please explain what's wrong with this c++ code?

Tags: c++, c++11

The program below is an example from Absolute C++ by Walter J Savitch. I'm trying to run this code but getting errors but I cant figure out why. This is an example of user defined functions. The function `round()` is supposed to return an `int` value after rounding a `double` value

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int round (double number);

int main()
{ 
    double doubleValue;
    char ans;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a double value: ";
        cin >> doubleValue;
        cout << "rounded that number is " << round(doubleValue) << endl;
        cout << "Again?" << endl;
        cin >> ans;
    }while(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');

    cout << "end of testing " << endl;
    return 0;
}

int round(double number)
{
   return static_cast<int>(floor(number + 0.5);
}
```

[1]:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABj8G.png
this is the errors that I'm getting.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: `cmath` already has `round`, my crystal ball says your compiler is complaining about your redefinition.

Comment: What @user657267 said, also, not knowing anything about the point of the code -- round() above doesn't actually round. 0.5 should be inside the parens with number.

Comment: Please state the errors you are getting and the compiler you're using since this code is not generating any errors in my case. (cl compiler.)

Comment: Please copy and paste the error for better support

Comment: added a screenshot of it :)

Comment: @CodingIsLife No, copy and paste the text of the error message.

Comment: 3.6.cpp:15:25: error: ambiguating new declaration of ‘int round(double)’
 int round (double number);
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:361:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:430,
                 from /usr/local/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/iostream:38,
                 from 3.6.cpp:11:

Comment: /usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:310:1: note: old declaration ‘double round(double)’
 __MATHCALLX (round,, (_Mdouble_ __x), (__const__));
 ^
3.6.cpp: In function ‘int round(double)’:
3.6.cpp:34:24: error: ambiguating new declaration of ‘int round(double)’
 int round(double number)
                        ^

Comment: In file included from /usr/include/features.h:361:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:430,
                 from /usr/local/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/iostream:38,
                 from 3.6.cpp:11:
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:310:1: note: old declaration ‘double round(double)’
 __MATHCALLX (round,, (_Mdouble_ __x), (__const__));
 ^

Comment: "`cin >> doubleValue;`" - any book that doesn't teach you how to check your input operations succeeded is IMHO best used as fuel for the fireplace (a better practice is e.g. `if (cin >> doubleValue) ...success...; else ...handle failure...;`, or putting the I/O operations into the loop condition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error round is already defined in another file, make a new one with a new name and it should work

```
int my_round (double number);

int main()
{ 
    // ... 
    cout << "rounded that number is " << my_round(doubleValue) << endl;   
    // ... 
}

int my_round(double number)
{
    return static_cast<int>(floor(number + 0.5));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, I don't know why you have implemented round() function, since there is a round() function is c.

Second, you have implemented round() function incorrectly. you need something like this:

```
int round(double num)
{
return static_cast<int>(num+0.5);
}
```

Comment: I'm just trying to run the code sample that's in the book and I'm a learner so I didn't know there's already a predefined round function :/